# grpc error: packets.SubmitCustomerRequest.details: object expected

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, rpc

I just created a proto file like this

```
service Customer {
  rpc SubmitCustomer(SubmitCustomerRequest) returns (SubmitCustomerResponse) {}
}

message SubmitCustomerRequest {
  string name = 1;
  map<string, google.protobuf.Any> details = 2;
}

message SubmitCustomerResponse {
  int64 id = 1;
}
```

The code itself works when I called this from the client. But, I'm having trouble with testing it directly from bloomrpc or postman.

```json
{
    "name": "great name",
    "details": {
      "some_details": "detail value",
      "some_int": 123
    }
}
```

it throws me this error when I tried to hit it

```bash
.packets.SubmitCustomerRequest.details: object expected
```

I think I'm aware that the problem is with the `details` syntax format when I hit it on postman, but I'm not sure what the correct format is supposed to be. I've tried modifying it with any other possible format and none works either.

Comment: When you do this from the client you can use protobuf library to convert your request protobuf message to text and then log/debug it.

Comment: @YuriGolobokov do you know how to do it on golang? i just randomly used a library on protobuf but it prints the `details` field multiple times as bunch of duplicates. not sure if it's the right one.

Comment: yes, that should be the right one as maps are represented as repeated messages for backwards compatibility: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#backwards_compatibility